# Codemirror not finding a textarea because DOM is not completely loaded

Tags: textarea, delay, startup, codemirror

i'm trying to embed w codemirror TextArea in an App built with Hype (Tumult). I have no problem to fireup codemirror on whatever textarea i insert in my php document.

But, when i try to target at a textarea from my JS design, the answer is always: textarea is null.

I bet that's because my textArea "comes on the scene" after codemirror has started.

Please: how could i delay the codeMirror firing up after i am sure my textarea id="myBox" is loaded ?

Ty

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for reading. I tried to play with changingState of loading page:

```
document.onreadystatechange = function () {
if(document.readyState === "complete"){
/* your code */
var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById("txtdef"), {
/* start codemirror */
});
}
}
```

And it's working.Great !